# How to copy every "_" from column to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy-paste

I have 2 columns A and B

A column have data

B column is empty

I want to copy every cell that contain "_" in A to be copied on column B with same cell number

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjCpE.jpg

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean same row number?

Comment: yes thats right

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want Column B for the same row as A to have A's value if A has a "_" then in B2, for example, put

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_",A2,1)),A2,"")
```

And drag down.

If you actually need A to move to B so A is empty you will need VBA.

[image: Formula]

Or with code:

```
Sub Move()

Dim loopRange As Range

Set loopRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5") 'change as appropriate

Dim currCell As Range

For Each currCell In loopRange

If InStr(1, currCell.Value, "_", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then

    currCell.Offset(, 1) = currCell
    currCell = vbNullString

End If

Next currCell

End Sub
```

If you have data in column B and want to move column A data to a different column change the number in this:

```
currCell.Offset(, 1) = currCell
```

where 1 is the number of columns to move to the right to another number e.g.

2 for column C, 3 for column D

e.g.

`currCell.Offset(, 2) = currCell` moves data to column C

You can also filter column A in place by adding a [filter](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2010/filtering-data/1/), right click,a nd then in the filter box, under where it says "Number Filters", type "*_*" in the empty box (without the ""). This will filter the list to the items with "_" in.

For GoogleSheets, which doesn't support wildcards (e.g. *) you simply go to data tab > add filter > then in filter box put "_" .

[image: Googlesheets filter]

Comment: yes if you drag the formula down. Or just use the code in a standard module and change this ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5") to your sheet and range e.g. Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A600000")

Comment: Code is probably easier! Unless you set your data up as a [table](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-excel-tables-for-quick-formula-auto-fill/)and enter the formula in the first cell of column B and the formula will automatically be autofilled down. You can also use autofill by clicking bottom left of first cell in column B after you have put the formula in.

Comment: I have one little problem, when I drag down, I have some text on column B and then the text disappears, is there any way to avoid this problem?

Comment: You have text already there before you drag down the formula? If so, put the formula in column C or a free column and just make sure it still has A in the formula e.g. =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_",A2,1)),A2,"")

Comment: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-excel-tables-for-quick-formula-auto-fill/ for autofill with table

Comment: Though your question did say B column is empty. :-) There is enough detail in the answer now for you to have a play.

Comment: is there somehow without affecting the text in column B or is it impossible? because I need everything in 1 column

Comment: You said you wanted to move from A to B. Do you want just values left in A that have "_" ? You can filter the range on column A with "*_*"

Comment: then how to do it with google sheets? I'm getting Error

Comment: In google sheets add fllter on column A and in text box just put _ See edit to answer at bottom.